# Cancelling async method from console keypress

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have following part of code

```
using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
  // Creating a task to listen to keyboard key press
  var keyBoardTask = Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Console.Write(" (press \'c\' to cancel)... ");
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
    {
      // Cancel the task
      cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
  });

  try
  {
    await LongRunningCancellableOperation(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled");
  }

  await keyBoardTask;
}
```

LongRunningCancellableOperation method takes for example 30 seconds of time.
When I commented out following part of code:

```
  // await keyBoardTask
```

the code works the same as when uncommented.
I can cancel execution of async method by using 'c' key from console in both cases.

The questions are:
1. Why this code works fine with commented out and uncommented line?:

```
  await keyBoardTask
```

2. How to correct implement cancelling async method from console by keypress?

Comment: `Task.Run` starts the task immediately (that's why the cancellation works). The line `await keyBoardTask` in its current location has no effect whatsoever because it's only reached after the `LongRunningCancellableOperation` is completed/canceled/failed.

Comment: await is a way of telling the runtime/compiler that the rest of the method should not be executed until the task has been finished. In your case rest of the method is nothing hence it does not matter whether you put await or not. For point 2, you said you can cancel in both cases, so why do you think it is not the right way (the only thing I would change is to let it be in the main thread...like a normal UI class and not in a task/background thread).

Comment: Subscribe to the [Console.CancelKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress) event and do `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` in the event handler. The event and therefore the cancellation token will be triggered when you press Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this code works fine with commented out and uncommented line?:

this line:

```
var keyBoardTask = Task.Run(() =>
```

starts the task which will print to the console and sit afterwards in this line:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey();
```

and wait for input. Parallel to this the second one starts and runs. Meanwhile the execution of the main thread is sitting in this line:

```
await LongRunningCancellableOperation(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

and **awaiting** the return.

This line:

```
await keyBoardTask;
```

hasn't been reached yet! So it has no influence on your program until now. The second await will only be reached **after** the long task has finished, and the main thread will only wait there if you have never pressed `c` and released the first task from it's misery of waiting for user input.

> How to correct implement cancelling async method from console by keypress?

This I find rather difficult to say, because I don't know the rest of your program. It depends on your other tasks preceding or following this one.
One important thing in your code is that you should take care of the `keyBoardTask`. It needs to be released from waiting for user input if the longrunning task has succeeded!